# Excel - Transpose a Cell into Rows with Paired Data

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a CSV export with the following layout:

| ID | Section A | Section B | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1, val2 | val3, val4, val5 | ... |
| 2 | val6, val7, val8 | val9, val10 | ... |

And I'd like to have the dataset transformed to the following output:

| ID | Section | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Section A | val1 |
| 1 | Section A | val2 |
| 1 | Section B | val3 |
| 1 | Section B | val4 |
| 1 | Section B | val5 |
| 2 | Section A | val6 |
| 2 | Section A | val7 |
| 2 | Section A | val8 |
| 2 | Section B | val9 |
| 2 | Section B | val10 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My challenge is that I have to deal with tens of thousands of these rows, so I want to be able to apply the same solution to the entire dataset.

I figured out how to transpose the comma separated values into multiple rows, but can't seem to figure out how to programmatically pair up the transposed values with the corresponding `ID` and `Section`.

Below is the VBA code I have for the transposition, in case anyone wants to see it:

```
Sub TransposeTest()
Dim rng As Range
Dim inputRng As Range, outputRng As Range
titleTxt = "Transpose Test"
Set inputRng = Application.Selection.Range("A1")
Set inputRng = Application.InputBox("Input cell:", titleTxt, inputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set outputRng = Application.InputBox("Output cell:", titleTxt, Type:=8)
output = VBA.Split(inputRng.Range("A1").Value, ",")
outputRng.Resize(UBound(output) - LBound(output) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(output)
End Sub
```

Comment: Tranformations like this are better executed using PowerQuery - which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @SpectralInstance - my version is 2108. I fiddled a bit with PowerQuery but I have virtually no experience with it, so produced only a partial solution. Perhaps I can dig deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit from arrays and split to transform data easily:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, s As Long
Dim MyData As Variant
Dim SubData As Variant
Dim TotalColumns As Long


MyData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
TotalColumns = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

Range("E1").Value = "ID"
Range("F1").Value = "Section"
Range("G1").Value = "Value"

k = 2 'initial row to paste data
For i = 2 To UBound(MyData) Step 1
    For j = 2 To TotalColumns Step 1 'j=2 because first column because it's ID
        SubData = Split(MyData(i, j), ", ")
        For s = 0 To UBound(SubData) Step 1
            Range("E" & k).Value = MyData(i, 1) 'ID always in first column
            Range("F" & k).Value = MyData(1, j) 'Section always in first row
            Range("G" & k).Value = SubData(s)
            k = k + 1
        Next s
    Next j
Next i

Erase SubData
Erase MyData

End Sub
```

[image]

I got the output in same worksheet but code can be easily adapted to make it in a different worksheet.

[image]

Comment: This looks promising! Yeah, I will need to dump the output to another sheet in the same file, but I should be able to figure that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the 9 cells in your table were configured as an Excel table named 'Data' then the M code below:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Section A", type text}, {"Section B", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Section A", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Section A"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {{"Section B", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Section B"),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Section"}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Value", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Trimmed Text")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

would render this result in PowerQuery
[image: Screenshot illustrating PowerQuery solution]
(you would need to have a *Split Column by Delimiter* step for each of your Sections)

Comment: This looks like another legit solution. I will try this method as well to get more familiar with PowerQuery. Thanks!